# Server 2008 Task Scheduler Mapped Drive Access C#

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying do get Server 2008's Task Scheduler to run a C# console app which backs up data to a mapped backup drive somewhere on FastHosts network.

I've written a test app which simply does this

Directory.CreateDirectory("Z:\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());

i.e. just creates a directory on the root of this Z drive.

This works fine when I just run the .exe but when I schedule it in Task Scheduler it doesn't create the directory but says the task has completed with return code 3762507597 - I can't find any info on what this means.

I'm running the task with the highest Admin privelages as far as I can see.

Answer (score 6):

If this ever helps someone else, the issue I had was due to the 'action' needing to have the 'Start in' path set to the same path as the application itself. Otherwise I'm guessing it's trying to write to the system root.

A bit cryptic!

Comment: Had a similar issue: migrating a service from Windows 2008 server to Windows 2019 server. The settings of the task in Task scheduler was the same, but on the new server the task fails with the error from the question. The task fails when it reaches the code: `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Logs.log", true); writer.WriteLine(...` , After setting the 'Start in' to be in the same directory it started working without problems. Even the eventviewer doesn't show an error, _only that some windows error reporting queue is triggered_

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why is now works but I replaced the mapped drive letter i.e. 'Z' with the full name i.e. \[IP address]]\C$ and it now works.

Some weird permissions thing no doubt.

Comment: I experienced the same thing. And I am sure I was using the same context for both a manual run and a task scheduler run.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an `AccessViolationException`, so I assume you are not running under the correct credentials.

Comment: Well, I'm sure you're right.
But in the Task Scheduler setup it says it's running as Administrator and I've checked the box which says 'Run with Highest Privelages'

Comment: Task Schedular option "Run with Highest Privelages"  worked for me